# word-break не переносит текст

Tags: css

Всем привет,

Нужно справа от чекбокса вывести текст и он выводится, но проблема в том, что текст длинный и не вмещяясь
в одну строку, ntrcn переносится он переносится на другую строку, но и чекбоксы уходят вверх
http://www.codeply.com/go/MWSsqNXrou

Я прописал    break-word для класса с определением параграфа :

```
p.notice_p{
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    border: 1px dotted navy;
}
```

но это не помогло.
А как правильно ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует указать ширину блока .hostel2_data_block или для параграфов (p.notice_p), в которых отображается текст, который нужно перенести. Таким образом, когда текст не поместится в параграф, он будет перенес на следующую строку. Сейчас перенос не работает, так как ширина параграфов ничем не ограничена.